# VisualForce Attachment isn't uploading

Tags: apex, attachment

I am trying to have a site that has a visualforce page allowing someone to upload an attachment with the new record that they are creating. I have the attachment passing at 95% code coverage but it doesn't seem to actually be working.

VF:

```
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Submit"/>
       <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Upload the Attachment" collapsible="false" dir="LTR" columns="1">
        <div id="upload" class="upload">                                   
            <apex:inputFile id="fileToUpload" value="{!fileBody}" filename="{!fileName}" styleClass="input-file"/>                            
        </div>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Apex Class:

```
public class dataSheetAttachment
{
    public Data_Feasibility_Request__c objdfr{get;set;}
    public Attachment myAttachment{get;set;}
    public string fileName{get;set;}
    public Blob fileBody{get;set;}

    public dataSheetAttachment(Apexpages.standardcontroller controller)
    {
        objdfr = (Data_Feasibility_Request__c)controller.getRecord();
        myAttachment = new Attachment();
    }
    public pagereference save()
    {
        if(myAttachment.Name == null)
        {
            insert objdfr;
        }
        if(myAttachment.Name != null)
        {
            insert objdfr;
            System.debug('@@@@@fileBody'+fileBody);    
            myAttachment = new Attachment();
            Integer i=0;
            myAttachment .clear();
            myAttachment.Body = fileBody;
            myAttachment.Name = fileName ;
            myAttachment.ParentId = objdfr.id;            
            insert myAttachment;   
        }             
       pagereference pr = Page.Thank_You;                          
       pr.setRedirect(true);
       return pr;
    }
}
```

Wondering if anyone knows what I might be missing?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it's not working?

Comment: The save is successful and a new record is created which is expected but when I try to use the upload function on the for the attachment the record is still created without an attachment on the record.

Comment: @JoshuaAnderson, please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the issue is `myAttachment.Name` is always null. That's why it is not attaching the file. Either you have assign this value in page or controller otherwise remove this `if` condition.

I have written this code and tested that file is getting attached to Account record. Though I am not creating Account record. Just taking the reference of AccountId and attaching to that record.

**Visualforce**

No changes have been made other than declaring `<apex:page>`

```
<apex:page StandardController="Account" extensions="AccountAttachment">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Submit"/>
                   <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Upload the Attachment" collapsible="false" dir="LTR" columns="1">
                <div id="upload" class="upload">                                   
                    <apex:inputFile id="fileToUpload" value="{!fileBody}" filename="{!fileName}" styleClass="input-file"/>                            
                </div>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class AccountAttachment
{
    public Account objdfr{get;set;}
    public Attachment myAttachment{get;set;}
    public String fileName{get;set;}
    public Blob fileBody{get;set;}
    public Id accountId {get;set;}

    public AccountAttachment(Apexpages.standardcontroller controller)
    {
        objdfr = (Account)controller.getRecord();
        accountId = (Id) controller.getId();
        myAttachment = new Attachment();
    }
    public pagereference save()
    {      
        System.debug('@@@@@fileBody'+fileBody);    
        myAttachment = new Attachment();
        myAttachment.Body = fileBody;
        myAttachment.Name = fileName;
        myAttachment.ParentId = accountId;            
        insert myAttachment;   

        return (new ApexPages.StandardController (new Account(Id=accountId))).view();
    }
}
```